# Deploy *.spapp to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-framework

I have created solutions using SharePoint Framework. I don't have any idea how I can deploy it to SharePoint.  I have *.spapp file, what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Just drag and drop the *.spapp on the app catalog to install it ;) on your farm.